# About Delphi / Generic / array's : why this doesn't compile?

Tags: arrays, delphi, generics

I'm wondering what is wrong in the generic code below (written in Delphi 10.4.1).
Moreover, is there another way to achieve the same goal ? I mean searching inside an array
(I know that I should use collection). Thanks in advance !

Regards

```
type
TDelphiExtention = class
public
  class function inside<T>(const value : T; const arr : array of T) : boolean;
end;

class function TDelphiExtention.inside<T>(const value : T; const arr : array of T) : boolean;
var
  i : integer;

begin
  result := true;
  for i := Low(arr) to High(arr) do begin
    if (arr[i] = value) then begin // E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type !!!
      exit;
    end;
  end;

  result := false; // Not found
end;

// This one compiles like a charm... But is not generic :(
function inside(const value : integer; const arr : array of integer) : boolean;
var
  i : integer;

begin
  result := true;
  for i := Low(arr) to High(arr) do begin
    if (arr[i] = value) then begin
      exit;
    end;
  end;

  result := false; // Not found
end;
```

Comment: It's helpful when saying that it *doesn't compile*, you include the **exact** compiler error message you're getting. It makes it much easier for us to locate the area where the problem is located. Please [edit] your post to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`T` could be literally anything. The compiler doesn't know how to compare for equality given an arbitrary type. For instance, suppose that `T` is a record. If you tried to write `A = B` where `A` and `B` were of that record type, that would also be a compiler error. Likewise for arrays, and so on.

You can use the facilities of the `System.Generics.Defaults` unit to obtain an equality comparer:

```
class function TDelphiExtention.inside<T>(const value: T;
  const arr: array of T): boolean;
var
  i: integer;
  comparer: IEqualityComparer<T>;
begin
  comparer := TEqualityComparer<T>.Default;

  for i := Low(arr) to High(arr) do
  begin
    if comparer.Equals(arr[i], value) then
    begin
      result := true;
      exit;
    end;
  end;

  result := false; // Not found
end;
```

Do beware though that not all types will have appropriate equality comparers, so you may want to offer an overload that accepts an equality comparer as an argument.

```
class function TDelphiExtention.inside<T>(const value: T;
  const arr: array of T; comparer: IEqualityComparer<T>): boolean;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := Low(arr) to High(arr) do
  begin
    if comparer.Equals(arr[i], value) then
    begin
      result := true;
      exit;
    end;
  end;

  result := false; // Not found
end;
```

FWIW, your method would be better named `Contains` since this would fit with the naming convention used by most other Delphi libraries.

Comment: Might also be worth plugging the Spring4d library which has this sort of functionality (and so much more)

Comment: Indeed, my bad ! Good point :p http://docs.spring4d.org/index.htm?Spring.TArray.Contains(T).htm

Answer (score -2):

Well, I've made some diggings and I'm a bit surprised on my findings.

- Unit `System.pas` defines `TArray<T>` as an alias to an `array of T`
- Unit `System.Generics.Collections` defines `TArray = class`
  holding only static class methods (already funny) but very few of the classic ones.
  Here no contains so far !
- Unit `Spring.Collections` defines a lot of interesting collections but no more support for the array one. In fact `CreateArray` did exist but have vanished...
  And documentation is quite often outdated :(
- Quickly looked at the unit `Rapid.Generics`, it seems too intrusive, no predicate search, does not fill my requirements

==> finally my naive approach seems to be missing everywhere !-)
My next question is, why array are so rejected ?
Still need `Single`, `First`, `Any` and their default variants

Last but not least, the proposed fix is great but just "postponed" the situation.

IEqualityComparer = interface
function Equals(const Left, Right: T): Boolean;

Why Delphi compiler can't interpret my `arr[i]` as `T` or even value as `T` directly?

```
if (value = value) then begin
   // Does not compile
end;
if (arr[i] = arr[i]) then begin
   // Idem
end;
```

Compiler is picky !

Comment: This doesn't answer the question